# Center images in dynamic RelativeLayout with negative margins

Tags: android, alignment

I am trying to create a layout that has a set of overlapped playing cards that are centered horizontally.  The overlap works but the cards are not centered.  If I draw a border around the cards then the relative layout appears to have included all the area that would have been used if negative margin had not been applied.  This total area is then centered.

How can I ensure that the extent of the relative layout is just the area containing the ImageViews for the playing cards so that I can center the playing cards horizontally?

This is the RelativeLayout definition

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/tNorth"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/vCardTable"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
        android:background="@drawable/losing_border"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15sp" >
    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the code

```
    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            if (isMiddle) {
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            }
            if (previousCard != null) {
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, previousCard.getId());
                params.setMargins(-pxPadding, 0, 0, 0);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by setting the width and height of the ImageView

```
            final int hPixels = (int) (100 * scale + 0.5f);
            final int wPixels = (int) (70 * scale + 0.5f);
            final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(wPixels, hPixels);
```

After this was set the layout was correct and I could also remove the setAdjustViewBounds

Answer (score 0):

you can ImageResource and ImageBackground for set border in pictures with padding, same as:

```
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@drawable/yourImageInCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/yourBorderForImage" />
```

also, you can used this code in hardCode:

```
    params.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Comment: Thanks Rahil, I tried that but no luck.  The playing card ImageView has setAdjustViewBounds set to true as, I was having issues when the image was scaled, not sure if this would cause a problem.